# Question about a conditional expectation

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, expectation

Let $\Omega = [0, 1]$. Let $P$ be the uniform probability law on $\Omega$. Let $X : [0, 1] → \mathbb R$ be a random variable such that $X(t) = t^2$ for all $ t ∈ [0, 1]$. I was asked to calculate $\mathbb E\left[X\,\middle | \left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]\right]$. I never learnt measure theory and this is what I tried:

$$\mathbb E\left[X\,\middle | \left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]\right] = \frac{\mathbb E\left(X\cdot \mathbf1_{\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]}\right)}{P\left(\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]\right)} = \frac1{1/4}\int_0^{\infty}P\left(X\cdot\mathbf 1_{\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]} >s\right)ds$$

Then I was told the last step is 
$$\int_0^{\infty}P\left(X\cdot\mathbf 1_{\left[0,\frac{1}{4}\right]} >s\right)ds=\int_0^{\frac{1}{4}}t^{2}dt$$

I spent a long time but could not figure out how to do the final step. Please help me!

thank you very much!

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------Edit:

I'm probably making unnecessary effort here. My major problem here is how to get the expectation without given pdf. The only way to get expectation that I know is through $$\int xf_X(x)dx$$ or$$\int_0^{\infty}P(X>s)ds$$ for positive random variables.
But they both seem not applicable here.

Comment: The last integral is easier to compute via pdf: $\mathbb{E}[g(X)] = \int_{\mathbb{R}} g(x) p(x) dx$, where $g$ is measurable, and $p$ is the pdf of $X$. Write this for $g(x) = x\mathbf{1}_{[0,1/4]}(x)$ and $p(x) = \mathbf{1}_{[0,1]}(x)$.

Comment: @zhoraster Thank you! But will you please elaborate a little more about why the pdf is $p(x) = 1_{[0,1]}(x)$?

Comment: Indeed you are making an unnecessary back and forth between the two formulas $E(Z)=\int_0^\infty P(Z>z)dz$ and $E(Z)=\int_0^\infty zf_Z(z)dz$ valid for a nonnegative random variable $Z$ with PDF $f_Z$.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice that $X(t) = t^2$. Then the pdf is different. However, you can write $X = Z^2$ where $Z$ is uniform. (So change $g$ in my comment to $x^2 \mathbf{1}_{[0,1/4]}(x)$).